# How to escape a leading dash in a PowerShell parameter

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I can run this PowerShell command without any issues:
`az keyvault secret set --name myPassword --vault-name myVault --value --% "3vFBJYp/FaH1C|Jr)Ee"`

However, this command fails:

```
PS > az keyvault secret set --name myPassword --vault-name myVault --value --% "-3vFBJYp/FaH1C|Jr)Ee"

'Jr)Ee' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\dev\edci\Seq\scripts> az keyvault secret set --name myPassword  --vault-name myVault --value --% "-3vFBJYp/FaH1C|Jr)Ee"
argument --value: expected one argument
```

Notice that the only difference is the leading dash.  I've tried several combinations of escaping the dash, but they didn't work or they conflict with other characters.  BTW, I settled on the `--%` with the password escaped with double-quotes because that performed the best in my tests.  Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively?tabs=powershell%2Cbash2#use-hyphen-characters-in-parameters):

> If a parameter's value begins with a hyphen, Azure CLI tries to parse it as a parameter name. To parse it as value, use = to concatenate the parameter name and value: --password="-VerySecret".

so this should work for you:

```
az keyvault secret set --name myPassword --vault-name myVault --value="-3vFBJYp/FaH1C|Jr)Ee"
```

Comment: That worked!  Thank you very much.  It was the end of a very long and late workday, and I didn't even think that I could be fighting with the Azure CLI.  Looking back at the error message, I can see how the message is different from typical PowerShell errors.  Thanks for the correction!